# Поиск последней строки в файле по символу 0A Tasm/Ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Нужно найти последнюю строку в текстовом файле и вывести ее на экран. 
Как я понял ,что нужно двигаться с конца файла и когда я встречу 0A, то что то нужно сделать.
Помогите разобраться как произвести поиск.

```
int 21h
mov AL,2
mov CX,FFFF
mov DX,FFFF; так я ставлю указатель на конец файла и сдвигаю на 2 (потому что первый символ будет -конец файла, а второй уже не известно)
```

Дальше по идее я должен сделать КАКОЕ то, и как сравнение с 0A.
После этого указатель сдвинется на 1 вперед.
поэтому я должен циклически сдвигать указатель на 1 пока не найду 0A.

Comment: Символ конца файла обычно в файл никто не пишет. так что последний символ файла скорее всего 0A, если последняя строка файла заканчивается переводом каретки, или последний значащий символ строки - если не заканчивается. Но в общем да, делать примерно как вы написали, только мне кажется что при смещении -1 (ffff:ffff) вы при чтении получите именно последний символ, потому как al=2,cx:dx=0 указатель ставится за концом файла и прочитать нельзя ничего. И для оптимизации я бы читал блоками, скажем по 512 байт

Comment: @Mike ой не совсем я так написал . Я хочу сдвинуть на FFFF FFFE т.е на -2. А потом циклически на FFFF FFFF т.е на -1. Но вот я не понимаю что я должен сравнивать с 0А. И как вывести текст после того как найду 0А

Comment: Вам надо после установки смещения прочитать файл функцией 3Fh (http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/dos_0066.php) при этом чтение 1 байта сдвинет указатель файла на этот байт, так что в цикле вам всегда надо будет ставить указатель на -2 от текущей (al=1) позиции. И когда вы найдете начало строки вам надо так же с помощью 3Fh прочитать всю строку в буфер в оперативной памяти и из него уже выводить на экран.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо , вроде понял.
Я сейчас постараюсь написать, и сюда отпишусь.
------
Еще один вопрос, а вот получается сколько байт это и есть длина строки?

Comment: Да, можно посчитать сколько раз отступали от конца файла плюс один (тот байт что в самом начале пропустили)

Comment: @Mike после того как в я вывел на экран. указатель снова в конце? просто мне теперь нужно файл создать, и в него эту строку записать. А в 40h написано -"Запись в файл, начиная с текущей позиции, байтов из области памяти. После записи указатель позиции в файле перемещается на число записанных байтов". Просто получается если он в конце , я опять повторяю ранее сделанные действия

Comment: вы строку один раз прочитали в оперативную память и после вывода на экран строка из памяти никуда не денется. Или вы по одному символу выводили. Так что берете и пишите эту строку из памяти в файл

Comment: @Mikle Спасибо вам!